# Power BI - Report Generation From Template

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I'm new to Power BI, so, please bear with me.

Is it possible to design a Power BI report or template without any data but only with schema and we then point the report to different data sets to generate mulitple reports from the same starting report/template?

I don't have enough knowledge to try this one yet.